# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.summary' has no attribute 'FileWriter'について

Tags: python, python3, tensorflow

以下のコードを実行すると

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.summary' has no attribute 'FileWriter'

と表示されます。何故でしょうか

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
a = tf.constant(10, name='10'
b = tf.constant(20, name='20')
c = tf.constant(30, name='30')
add_op = tf.add(a, b, name='mul')
mul_op = tf.multiply(add_op, c, name='mul')
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
res = sess.run(mul_op)
print(res)
tf.summary.FileWriter('./logs', sess.graph)`
```

Tensorflowのバージョンは2です。

Comment: Tensorflowのバージョンはいくつでしょうか？

Comment: バージョン２になります

Answer (score 1):

`tf.summary.FileWrite` は Tensorflow 1.x には[存在していました](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/summary/FileWriter)が Tensorflow 2.0 では削除されており、代わりに `tf.summary.create_file_writer` があります。質問者さんのプログラムでは Tensorflow 1 流で書いてらっしゃるようなので、とりあえずの解決法として `tf.compat.v1.summary` を使うことで回避できます。

```py
tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter('./logs', sess.graph)
```

より Tensorflow 2 流に書くのであれば、[eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager) を意識して全体的に書き直す必要があります。詳しくはドキュメントの ["Effective TensorFlow 2"](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2) や ["Migrating tf.summary usage to TF 2.0"](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/migrate) を見てください。